# onDiscoverCharacteristicResults not called because of android.os.DeadObjectException

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola-droid

using the sample_apk_icsActivity app supplied in the motorola ICS R2 add-on, i am able to successfully connect to my BLE peripheral running the HRM profile....   i then create new BluetoothGattService object, at which time discovery of characteristics appears to begin....

using a packet sniffer, everything appears "normal".... at the end of the characteristic discovery process -- when i'd expect a callback through my IBluetoothGattProfile.Stub, i see a log message from the underlying BluetoothService reporting a DeadObjectException....   from the prior log messages, it would appear the service did find some characteristics and was preparing to give me callback....

again, i've been using the motorola sample app "as is"....

thanks....

Comment: some more data -- this does appear to work after i completely reboot the phone...   i can sometimes run the app one more time, with the callback being properly invoked....   after a while, however, i see this DeadObjectException....   is there something i might do when i reload my phone during development -- short of rebotting the device???   i does sound the underlying service is still holding on to a callback object from a previous incarnation of my app....  i don't want to necessarily stop the service, however

Comment: Excuse me , do you solve this problem ? I have see the `E/BluetoothGatt( 3667): android.os.DeadObjectException`

Answer (score 0):

You may have a concurrency issue. Where are you getting Gatt from ? If you send him to an another thread, he might have been destroyed in his original one.